# MySQL 5.5 upgrade 'broke' Wordpress

Tags: mysql

I upgraded from Debian 6 to 7 and during the upgrade, MySQL asked for new root password, I was little confused but typed it anyways. I guess this created a new database called 'mysql', because now there is 'wordpress' and 'mysql' directories:

```
# ls /var/lib/mysql/
debian-5.1.flag  debian-5.5.flag  ibdata1  ib_logfile0  ib_logfile1  mysql mysql_upgrade_info   performance_schema  wordpress
```

I queried the 'wordpress' database (correct one) with mysql-client and seems like data is still there. However, it doesn't load anything from the 'wordpress' database when I go to my website (except the index.php page). My admin page and media content is also unavailable, so I'm guessing it's a MySQL side problem.

My wp-config.php is correct, I haven't touched it (uses the wordpress DB). I have no idea where to look for.

Here is how my page looks like:

[image: Unable to load.]

**Edit:** It's not about the permissions. I tried the other DB called mysql and it went in to the WordPress installation as it should. Both mysql and wordpress have the same rights. Also mysql_upgrade fails:

```
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Comment: if you see anything at all then there was a valid conection and data extraction from your DB. If there was no access you would be prompted with a DB error message. In you screenshot it seems like an image url returns a 404 error, I would start with investigating it, checking file permissions etc.

Comment: Yes. That's why it's so weird, it seems to connect... but can't find any data.

Comment: It's not about permissions. I tested the newly created mysql DB and it went to WordPress installation. The mysql  DB has same rights as the wordpress DB in /var/lib/mysql.

Comment: I meant file permissions, not DB permissions. Check if the urls are correct then the file permissions. If the urls are incorrect then you have some data corruption, but if you see the right active theme in the dashboard then it is not very likely

Comment: I was talking about file permissions. What do you mean by urls are correct?

Comment: does the css is being loaded from the proper url?

Comment: If you mean: "does the domain.com/wp-login.php page look same as earlier?" the answer is no. Main page looks also very different. It says "Responsive Theme powered by WordPress" but I think it's statically generated.

Comment: if you use the responsive theme then that message means that the connection to DB was good enough to bring the theme name. I realy don't see anything related to a DB in your problem.

Comment: I see. I did chmod -R 777 www/ to entire wordpress directory and it's not helping.

Comment: Your themes CSS and upload folder isn't loading, most likely a file permission issue. Eitherway this is either too localised or a hosting issue, you require mysql and Debian Apache/Nginx knowledge here, not WordPress PHP knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to take DB and site backup and see if you can get it working on local server or any other server, if you do get it running the problem is with the way server probably changed some settings while upgrading.

Also in the screenshot image isn't loaded, but can you open developer tools in your favorite browser and see what path is it looking to get the image and can you access it just by going to that url?
Btw if you can't access that image by entering it's path, perhaps check who owns them files.. i'm guessing owner and group should be www-data:www-data

Thanks